# How to clear an histogram in OpenCV 3.0

Tags: c++, opencv

I am kind of new in opencv. I am trying to clear an histogram but I can not find how to do it in OpenCV 3.0. I found some info about the version 2.4 but it does not work. thank you!

Comment: "_it doesn't work_" why and where?

Comment: histogram.setTo(cv::Scalar::all(0));

Comment: Sorry for the delay,

Comment: Sorry for the delay, What I am trying to do is a sum and differences of histogram for features extraction. What I am doing is sum and substracting each pixel with r=1 and tetha=0,45&90. I am using three matrix type Mat to storage each operation(Mat SH(r=1,tetha=0) and so on. For some reason when I use several images of the same class to train a classifier (minimal distance), the features vector for the first image is correct, but for the rest of the images is returning incorrect values. By the way What I am calculating is entropy, energy and homogeneity.

Comment: here is my code where I am calculating the histogram with 6 different matrix, 3 for addition for theta=0.45,90 and 3 for subtraction.

Comment: calcHist(&SH1,1, channels,Mat(),hist,1,&histsize,ranges,true,true);
        calcHist(&SH2,1, channels,Mat(),hist,1,&histsize,ranges,true,true);
        calcHist(&SH3,1, channels,Mat(),hist,1,&histsize,ranges,true,true);
        calcHist(&DH1,1, channels,Mat(),hist1,1,&histsize,ranges1,true,true);
        calcHist(&DH2,1, channels,Mat(),hist1,1,&histsize,ranges1,true,true);
        calcHist(&DH3,1, channels,Mat(),hist1,1,&histsize,ranges1,true,true);

Comment: this the code where I am calculating the sum://Sum
for (r=1;r<img3.rows-1;r++)  {float* ptr_img = img3.ptr<float>(r);//tetha=zero
 float* ptr_img45 = img3.ptr<float>(r-1);//tetha=45 90
 float* ptr_sh1 = SH1.ptr<float>(r-1);
 float* ptr_sh2 = SH2.ptr<float>(r-1);
 float* ptr_sh3 = SH3.ptr<float>(r-1);
 for (c=1;c<img3.cols-1;c++)
 {
                            ptr_sh1 [c-1] = ptr_img [c] + ptr_img [c+1];
                            ptr_sh2 [c-1] = ptr_img [c] + ptr_img45 [c+1];
                            ptr_sh3 [c-1] = ptr_img [c] + ptr_img45 [c];
                        }
                }